# Why is the output different for both print statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
str1="This is a Case "
print(str1.swapcase())
print(str1)
```

[image: Results]

I expect the output for both print statements to be swapped as:
"tHIS IS A cASE" but the output for first print is "tHIS IS A cASE" and second print is the original `str1`.

Comment: Probably (don't know python) because swapcase returns a new string and does not change the original variable

Answer (score 1):

[`swapcase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase) doesn't change the string that you call it on, it returns a new string. If you want to change the original string, you have to reassign it with the returned value.

```
str1 = str1.swapcase()
```

Comment: I tried, apparently we need to assign to a new string since they are immutable. So, str2=str1.swapcase(). Thank you!